# ERROR: JAVA_HOME is set to an invalid directory: *\.vscode\extensions\

Tags: spring-boot, gradle, environment-variables

I'm trying to build a sample Spring Boot application with Gradle, When  i run "**gradle build**" command,I'm getting this error

> "JAVA_HOME is set to an invalid directory: C:\Users\[USER]\.vscode\extensions\redhat.java**"

I have tried to update my JAVA_HOME in environment variables, I even deleted the JAVA_HOME variable, but I keep getting this error.

**Note that I ran the command line outside of vscode, in a separate command prompt, but still nothing, Gradle still uses that path as JAVA_HOME.**

Can some someone help me here ?

Answer (score 0):

**I SOLVED IT**

I think in somehow I have installed a **Gradle extension in VS Code**, When I checked all my path variables I found that

> C:[USER]\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin

is on top of

> C:\Gradle\bin

Means that the Gradle commands executed by VS code extension

**I have only change the order of the environment variables by putting Gradle bin path in the top of all**

**The order is every important!!**